# Azure Logic Apps create JSON array from separate received xml

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am new to Azure and have to create JSON Array from separate  XML messages received by the logic app. The logic app requests data and receives the response in XML format.  I proposed an approach that is saving the message in Azure storage then through the Azure function create the JSON array. Is this approach affect the performance?  Is there any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways where you can completely rely on Logic apps without involving Azure functions

Consider this to be the sample xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<PurchaseOrder PurchaseOrderNumber="99503" OrderDate="1999-10-20">
  <Address Type="Shipping">
    <Name>Adam Murphy</Name>
    <Street>123 Maple Street</Street>
    <City>Mill Valley</City>
    <State>CA</State>
    <Zip>10999</Zip>
    <Country>Ireland</Country>
  </Address>
  <Address Type="Billing">
    <Name>Tai Yee</Name>
    <Street>8 Oak Avenue</Street>
    <City>Old Town</City>
    <State>PA</State>
    <Zip>95819</Zip>
    <Country>Ireland</Country>
  </Address>
  <DeliveryNotes />
</PurchaseOrder>
```

**WAY-1**

You can directly convert xml to json using `json(xml(triggerBody()))`
Here is the logic app for your reference -

[image]

**output**

[image]

If you want to have a custom json, then you can create one using `Parse_Json` and `Compose` Connectors.

[image]

Here I'm just taking the output of `Compose` Connector to `Parse_Json` in order to parse the resultant Json to get the custom JSON script. Below is the Json I'm trying to create.

```
{
  "PurchaseOrder": {
    "OrderNumber": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['PurchaseOrder']?['@PurchaseOrderNumber']}",
    "PurchaseDate": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['PurchaseOrder']?['@OrderDate']}",
    "Location": [
      {
        "Name": "@{items('For_each')?['Name']}",
        "Address": "@{items('For_each')?['Street']},@{items('For_each')?['City']},@{items('For_each')?['State']},@{items('For_each')?['Country']},@{items('For_each')?['Zip']}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**output**

[image]

[image]

Here is the code view of my logic app. You can directly use this to get the exact workflow in your logic app.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@json(xml(triggerBody()))",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "For_each": {
                "actions": {
                    "Compose_2": {
                        "inputs": {
                            "PurchaseOrder": {
                                "Location": [
                                    {
                                        "Address": "@{items('For_each')?['Street']},@{items('For_each')?['City']},@{items('For_each')?['State']},@{items('For_each')?['Country']},@{items('For_each')?['Zip']}",
                                        "Name": "@{items('For_each')?['Name']}"
                                    }
                                ],
                                "OrderNumber": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['PurchaseOrder']?['@PurchaseOrderNumber']}",
                                "PurchaseDate": "@{body('Parse_JSON')?['PurchaseOrder']?['@OrderDate']}"
                            }
                        },
                        "runAfter": {},
                        "type": "Compose"
                    }
                },
                "foreach": "@body('Parse_JSON')?['PurchaseOrder']?['Address']",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Parse_JSON": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Foreach"
            },
            "Parse_JSON": {
                "inputs": {
                    "content": "@outputs('Compose')",
                    "schema": {
                        "properties": {
                            "?xml": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "@@version": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            },
                            "PurchaseOrder": {
                                "properties": {
                                    "@@OrderDate": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "@@PurchaseOrderNumber": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "Address": {
                                        "items": {
                                            "properties": {
                                                "@@Type": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "City": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "Country": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "Name": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "State": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "Street": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "Zip": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            "required": [
                                                "@@Type",
                                                "Name",
                                                "Street",
                                                "City",
                                                "State",
                                                "Zip",
                                                "Country"
                                            ],
                                            "type": "object"
                                        },
                                        "type": "array"
                                    }
                                },
                                "type": "object"
                            }
                        },
                        "type": "object"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ParseJson"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

**WAY-2**

You can use liquid templates in order to convert xml to json using `Transform XML to JSON` Connector. For more information you can refer [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61486553/how-to-transform-from-xml-to-json-in-azure-logic-apps-using-liquid) and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48928189/logic-apps-liquid-connector-transform-xml).

**REFERENCES:**
[Logic App: Basic XML to JSON Expression Conversion](https://johnokeeffe.ie/2020/11/01/logic-app-basic-xml-json-conversion.html)

Comment: Thank you @SwethaKandikonda-MT , I have a question if the  XML messages received separately, as the XML message in your example  <Address1></Address1> will be received then   <Address2></Address2>  after a while. Saving the XML as Json in azure storage will affect the performance of logic Apps

Comment: @Alloylo Can I know from where are you trying retrieving xml